# How to setup the dependency for the Forge library?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forge, angularjs-module

I am trying to include this library (Digital Bazaar / Forge) in my project:
https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge

To include the dependency and have the forge object available through my `angularjs` app, I followed the steps on minifying the code and injecting the link in index.html:

```
npm install
npm run minify

<script src="js/forge.min.js"></script>
```

This works fine when I test it in a cloud environment (nodejs project in cloud9), but when I deploy the app using `Phonegap Build`, the dependency and the object `forge` dont seem to be available on the device.

What am I doing wrong and how to solve it?